# How to work with the DocuSign JWT flow using the PHP SDK

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, docusignapi

I have an application in which I use the DocuSign API to read data from envelopes.

Up until recently I was using this package: https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/Laravel-Docusign and the only reason I've stopped is because DocuSign is now enforcing the use of OAuth2, whereas before it was just email, password and an integration key.

I did a lot of reading and also found a starting point on the issues within the above package on GitHub.

Note that I'm using the PHP SDK. Here is my attempt.

```
<?php
namespace App\DocuSign;

use DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient;
use DocuSign\eSign\Client\Auth\OAuth;
use DocuSign\eSign\Configuration;
use Throwable;

/**
 * Helper class to generate a DocuSign Client instance using JWT OAuth2.
 *
 * @see
 *
 */
class OAuthClient
{
    /**
     * Create a new DocuSign API Client instance using JWT based OAuth2.
     */
    public static function createApiClient()
    {
        $config = (new Configuration())->setHost(config('docusign.host'));
        $oAuth = (new OAuth())->setOAuthBasePath(config('docusign.oauth_base_path'));

        $apiClient = new ApiClient($config, $oAuth);

        try {
            $response = $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken(
                config('docusign.integrator_key'),
                config('docusign.user_id'),
                config('docusign.private_key'),
                'signature impersonation',
                60
            );

            if ($response) {
                $accessToken = $response[0]['access_token'];

                $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $accessToken);

                $apiClient = new ApiClient($config);

                return $apiClient;
            }
        } catch (Throwable $th) {
            // If consent is required we just need to give the consent URL.
            if (strpos($th->getMessage(), 'consent_required') !== false) {
                $authorizationUrl = config('docusign.oauth_base_path') . '/oauth/auth?' . http_build_query([
                    'scope' => 'signature impersonation',
                    'redirect_uri' => config('docusign.redirect_url'),
                    'client_id' => config('docusign.integrator_key'),
                    'response_type' => 'code'
                ]);

                dd($authorizationUrl);
            }
        }

        return $apiClient;
    }
}
```

To use this in another controller is like so.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\DocuSign\OAuthClient;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the welcome page.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $client = OAuthClient::createApiClient();

        dd($client);
    }
}
```

There are two issues with this however.

1. I don't really want a random DocuSign call to end up with a random end user being told they need to provide consent. As I'm using one account for all API requests I'm assuming I can do this before launch and I'd be all good?
2. The underlying class has a method called `refreshAccessToken()` but I don't really see when I could use it? I'll post the source below.

```
    /**
     * Refresh Access Token
     *
     * @param string $client_id DocuSign OAuth Client Id(AKA Integrator Key)
     * @param string $client_secret The secret key you generated when you set up the integration in DocuSign Admin console.
     * @param string $code The authorization code
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws ApiException
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function refreshAccessToken($client_id = null, $client_secret = null, $refresh_token = null)
    { 
        if (!$client_id) { 
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Missing the required parameter $client_id when calling refreshAccessToken'); 
        } 
        if (!$client_secret) { 
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Missing the required parameter $client_secret when calling refreshAccessToken'); 
        } 
        if (!$refresh_token) { 
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Missing the required parameter $refresh_token when calling refreshAccessToken'); 
        }
        $resourcePath = "/oauth/token"; 
        $queryParams = []; 
        $integrator_and_secret_key = "Basic " . utf8_decode(base64_encode("{$client_id}:{$client_secret}")); 
        $headers = [ 
            "Authorization" => $integrator_and_secret_key, 
            "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        ];
        $postData = [ 
            "grant_type" => "refresh_token", 
            "refresh_token" => $refresh_token, 
        ];
        list($response, $statusCode, $httpHeader) = $this->callApi($resourcePath, self::$POST, $queryParams, $postData, $headers, null, null, true);
        if (isset($response->access_token))  
            $this->config->addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "{$response->token_type} {$response->access_token}");  
        return [$this->getSerializer()->deserialize($response, '\DocuSign\eSign\Client\Auth\OAuthToken', $httpHeader), $statusCode, $httpHeader]; 
    }
```

3. In the dump below which is just `dd($response[0])` you can see it gives an expiration but there is no refresh token, does this mean I would have to check the token once an hour and try to refresh it?
4. Finally, if I encrypt it, is it safe to store the access token in the storage folder?

Hopefully this is actually pretty straightforward but I'll amend my question if necessary.

[image]

Comment: This blog post was intended for Laravel users but it does work for any PHP integration https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/send-document-laravel-jwt-grant-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't really want a random DocuSign call to end up with a random end
> user being told they need to provide consent. As I'm using one account
> for all API requests I'm assuming I can do this before launch and I'd
> be all good?

Yes, you'll be all good. Notice, it's not one account but one user, if you use a single user all the time, consent was given once and done and you'll never have to give consent again.

> The underlying class has a method called refreshAccessToken() but I
> don't really see when I could use it? I'll post the source below.

This method is for Auth Code Grant. With JWT whenever you need a new token - you just make the same API call you made to obtain the first time. No need to refresh with JWT, just get a new one.

> In the dump below which is just dd($response[0]) you can see it gives
> an expiration but there is no refresh token, does this mean I would
> have to check the token once an hour and try to refresh it?

Best practice with JWT is - whenever your app needs a token - you obtain a new one. The exception may be if you have to make 2 consecutive API calls, then you  can reuse the same token. But you don't have to necessarily measure time to determine token expiration, just obtain a new one every time.

> Finally, if I encrypt it, is it safe to store the access token in the
> storage folder?

Where did you store the account password in your code when you used legacy auth before? The access token is just like a password. Do not store it where there's a chance someone may get it. If you use something secure - that's ok, but it's your responsibility to secure it.

Comment: Hi, really appreciate this in depth answer. I'm relatively new to JWT but this makes a lot of sense. Especially the bit about not actually needing to reftresh.